# Get all data in single db call and filter it in Controller - Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on a web applicaiton, where on a page, there are 3 different sections where some data of type x, y and z to be displayed respectively.

In database, there is a table(userinfo) whith 2 columns(Data, Type(x,y,z))

**Current design:**

On pageLoad, I have 3 different mehtods in controller and model to get data x, y and z. ex: getxdata ,getydata, getzdata.

**Method 1:**

```
  $query= $this->db->query("SELECT *
            FROM userinfo
            WHERE type=x
         ");
```

**Method 2:**

```
  $query= $this->db->query("SELECT *
            FROM userinfo
            WHERE type=y
         ");
```

**Method 3:**

```
$query= $this->db->query("SELECT *
        FROM userinfo
        WHERE type=z
     ");
```

There I am making 3 calls to db on a single page, which could cause performance issues.

**What I am looking for is:**

```
$query= $this->db->query("SELECT *
        FROM userinfo
        WHERE type in ('x','y','z')
     ");
```

Is there any way I can make a single call like above query and then in controller I could filter data based on values of `type` column using for loop??
(I need to display data on page in different sections depending on type of data)

Is there anyway to do this in codeigniter?

And I would also welcome on suggestions on which method would be peroformance friendly!

Thanks for help.

Comment: `What I am looking for is:`  in this section your query is completely correct so go for it and then filter based on type.Or you can change query like this simply:-`$query= $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM userinfo");`

Comment: @AlivetoDie Yeah. But How do I filter it in php? I have to display data on different sections of page depending on type of data.

Comment: Get all content from db with above query  (Alive to Die) & at the time of display just check the if condition like if(content==x){//display} same form next element

Comment: @pAsh I am aware of manual ways to do that. I am looking for any predefined methods to do that more efficiently in CodeIgniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter x,y, and z types like,

```
$query= $this->db->query("SELECT *
        FROM userinfo
        WHERE type in ('x','y','z')
     ");
return $query->result_array();
```

You can use `result` to filter your type field like,

```
$xArr = array_filter($result, function($k) {
    return $k['type'] == 'x'; // same for y and z
}
```